# Is there an OCaml equivalent of the [<RequireQualifiedAccess>] attribute for DUs in F#?

Tags: f#, ocaml, discriminated-union

In F# programs I prefer to use

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type MyType =
    | FirstOption of string
    | SecondOption of int
```

so that in code that uses `MyType` I am forced to write `MyType.FirstOption` instead of just `FirstOption`.  Is there any way to force this in OCaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a similar effect by defining the type in a module.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# module MyType = struct
    type t = FirstOption of string | SecondOption of int
    end    ;;
module MyType : sig type t = FirstOption of string | SecondOption of int end
# MyType.FirstOption "abc";;
- : MyType.t = MyType.FirstOption "abc"
# FirstOption "abc";;
Error: Unbound constructor FirstOption
#
```

If you do it this way, the name of the type (as you can see) is MyType.t.

Comment: I don't think that's what is required. In your example, I can `open MyType` and then write simply `FirstOption`,  without the prefix. The mentioned attribute in F# makes it impossible.

Comment: But I'm sure you can define some kind of synonym in the local scope and use that, which you might consider similar to using `open`. In fact it might be nice to be able to define an OCaml module that can't be opened with `open`.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask that but .... why do you want to force how the client code look like? :|

Comment: @Drup: In general `[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]` is used when you have a module or type that has members or cases that would shadow other useful values if opened.

Comment: @Tarmil: Well, the OCaml compiler can warn you about that, I agree with Drup. Plus nothing stays in the way of naming all of your constructors with a convention like `MyType_FirstOption "abc"`.

Comment: I prefer, and I think it's still generally accepted practice, to keep `open` to a minimum in OCaml and preferring qualifying fully or opening locally.